# BIRT XML data source url is requested several times

Tags: birt

I have a BIRT report which makes use of an XML data source. The location of this data source is provided by a parameter which holds a URL.

At first glance everything works fine.

However, when I look at the log provided by the back-end application that serves the actual XML files used for the reports I can see that the URL is requested quite a lot. It's not uncommon that while processing a single report the data source url is called 10 times or more.

Is there anything I can do to make BIRT only request the URL once?

I've already enabled "Needs cache for data-engine" for all the Data Sets.

I've also looked at the HTTP headers BIRT sends when requesting the URL. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support any kind of HTTP level caching.

Is there something else I can try?